# get id from displayname Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It’s almost 3 hours since I’ve been looking for a way to get a person’s ID from their discord server display name.
I have tried everything but nothing works every time I try a method it returns me each time "null" or "undefined".

Do you have a method that works please?

Sincerely,

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to be able to get a member's id given their display name?

Comment: I think for the future it would be better, if you show us what you have tried instead of just writing you have already tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the discord server:

```js
await <guild>.members.fetch();
const member = <guild>.members.cache.find(m => m.displayName === 'xxx')
const userID = member.user.id
```

To search all servers, use forEach

```js
var member;
var found;
await <client>.guilds.fetch();
<client>.guilds.cache.forEach(async g => {
   if(found) return;
   await g.members.fetch();
   if(g.members.cache.find(m => m.displayName === 'xxx')) {
      member = g.members.cache.find(m => m.displayName === 'xxx');
      found = true;
      //guild member is stored in variable member
   }
})
```

Comment: Best to follow conventions and indent your code, especially if you're going to post as an answer. And although it's not as big of an issue, only use `var` when working with older technologies

Comment: I had to use var so that it was in the global scope, and could be changed, also, I wrote it on mobile

Comment: Global variables can be defined with `let` and `const` as well, as long as the definition is in the global environment. `var` variables actually get hoisted by default